# Script to prompt to accept DMGR signer certificate of WAS from Client linux machine

Tags: linux, ssl, ant, websphere, jython

I'm trying to connect to Websphere via RMI using Websphere java classes as a macro in my ANT script to invoke Jython script. But while connecting to WAS DMGR, my scripts hangs as it doesn't prompt to accept the signer certificate to my client machine truststore. is there any command to make it prompt to accept the certificate. My objective is to run a jython script remotely in a client machine to connect to a WAS DMGR server. But for this, the SSL signer certificate needs to be added in my Client server and I want this to be prompted(in case of new WAS servers).Any advise?

Need something like below to prompt to accept certificate(y or n) which is not happening now..

*** SSL SIGNER EXCHANGE PROMPT ***
SSL signer from target host 192.174.1.5 is not found in truststore 
C:/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr/etc/trust.p12.
Verify that the digest value matches what is displayed at the server in the following signer information:

Subject DN:    CN=hostname.austin.ibm.com, O=IBM, C=US
Issuer DN:     CN=hostname.austin.ibm.com, O=IBM, C=US
Serial number: 1128544457
Expires:       Thu Oct 20 15:34:17 CDT 2006
SHA-1 Digest:  91:A1:A9:2D:F2:7D:70:0F:04:06:73:A3:B4:A4:9C:56:9D:A8:A3:BA
MD5 Digest:    88:72:C5:88:00:1C:A7:FA:D6:EB:04:88:AC:A1:C9:13

**Add signer to the truststore now? (y/n)** y

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint: there is a tool called '**retrieveSigners.sh**' in the WebSphere installation that could help you:

[retrieveSigners](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_retrievesigners.html) (IBM documentation)

It should be something like this:

```
retrieveSigners.sh CellDefaultTrustStore ClientDefaultTrustStore \
-autoAcceptBootstrapSigner \
-host "$SERVER" \
-port "$PORT" \
-localAlias "$SERVER-cert" \
-conntype SOAP \
-trace
```

I hope it could help you.

Best wishes